# Measuring soil dampness with terracotta pot

Tags: watering, containers

[image]
I recently got this small citrus tree and it says it is supposed to be watered when the soil is dry 1 - 2 inches deep. I've been measuring this with my finger. This is my first time using a terracotta pot and I've noticed that I seem to see the pot drying when the soil is dry as shown in the picture. I was wondering if this is considered a reliable way to judge when to water.

Comment: Does the pot have a drainage hole ?  Because judging soil moisture is problematic , generally one uses soil with good drainage and lets excess water drain from the hole ( ideally).

Comment: It does have a hole in the bottom and I'm using citrus soil (it is a citrus plant) so it does drain excess water really well.